# How to create a VPN over Tor connection on android?

Tags: vpn, openvpn, tor

I am trying to setup a VPN over TOR connection on my phone so that the connection looks like this: -

My device -> Tor -> VPN -> Internet

I use orbot , OpenVPN connect app and also orwall. I ran orbot and configured openVPN to use Tor proxy (localhost: 9050). But the vpn wont connect.

But when i looked up it says that this method works in windows which handles sockets in a peculiar way. In other OS, one has to deal with some 'infinite routing loop' problem. ( comunication between tor and  tor entry relay would fall back into the vpn) Eddie for linux and OS X solves this problem by talking to the Tor Control to detect and route correctly the guard IP addresses.

How do i bypass this infinite routing loop problem?
Is there any way to exclude orbot from using the VPN connection ? Or is 'VPN over Tor' impossible on Android?

Comment: Try this [adguard on ToR](https://m.facebook.com/adguardfilter/posts/1741690096102136:0)

Comment: I tried this now. Went to proxy settings of adguard and used  tor socks5 proxy.  It says that the vpn is connected but i cant access the internet. And orbot is showing no data transfer. Is it again because of the infinite routing?

Comment: Did you  go to the settings on orbot which allows you to choose which apps to run through Tor and select?

Comment: Its 4.2.2 jellybean. Well adguard sets up a local vpn server. So the ip isnt changing. Well i was trying to route a remote vpn traffic through Tor. I still dont know if adguard uses a remote VPN though.

Comment: Do you mean if i have to enable Transparent Proxying on Tor and select the apps to route through orbot ?

Comment: Adguard creates a [local VPN on your device](https://adguard.com/en/adguard-android/overview.html).  Yes, as I recollect you need to select apps on the orbit for tor app

Comment: I don't think that's possible - at least I have not heard of it

Comment: Ok. But what i needed wasnt a local vpn. Well it actually looks like this :- my device ->encrypt by vpn -> encrypt by tor  -> tor entry relay -> tor exit relay (decrypt tor) -> decrypt by vpn -> internet . So the ip websites will see is vpn server ip and not tor exit node ip.

Comment: Two options you can try (not tested by me) 1. Use the experimental VPN option in the Orbot for app 2. Connect to VPN first as explained here http://tor.stackexchange.com/q/9993

Comment: I will check in after a while to see what worked :)

Comment: That post explains a Tor over VPN connection (not VPN over TOR). Tor over VPN is less secure unless your VPN provider does not keep any logs. Adguard would have solved my problem if it used a remote VPN server because it supports proxy settings(to use tor proxy) as well as app exclusions(excludes orbot from using VPN). The experimental VPN option on orbot just allow all apps to run through Tor using the VPN feature of android. It does not really use any external / remote vpns, it just uses a local VPN to globally route all traffic from all apps through tor i guess.